# Cannot access Angular NG1 Service from Angular 2+ Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, service, components

I have tried every example I have found, and am still unable to call an NG1 Service from my Angular Component.

Is this even possible in the way I am describing below?

Service is defined like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.shared.services').factory('ng1TestService', ng1TestService);

function ng1TestService() {

    var getGreeting = function () {
        return "HELLO DOM! GOOD JOB!";
    }

    return {
        getGreeting: getGreeting
    }

}
```

I am calling upgrade on this service in my component:

```
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider('ng1TestService')
```

Component Constructor:

```
    constructor(@Inject('ng1TestService') ng1TestService : any) {
    var hello = ng1TestService.getGreeting();
}
```

PROBLEMS:

- I get an error saying that there is no Provider for ng1Test Service
- I cannot call the NG1 Service
- I had to add the "any" cast to resolve an error
- It is not possible for me to add this Service to my "Providers" list since it is not in TS format

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!